# how to declare routes for editing multiple sub resources in a single page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I build a shop system. Im working on the admin pages.

Editing an order shall be split on two pages:
- one page for editing the base data of the order (like addresses, status etc)
- a second page for editing the line items

Declaring routes for the first page is quite easy.
resources :orders works just fine and gives me all the routes

But on the second page, I want to edit all line items on a single page.
So the way of declaring a subresoruce does not work for me.

Aka:

```
resources :orders do
   resources :items
end
```

builds routes for editing and updating routes for individual items,
like

```
UPDATE /order/:id/item/:item_id
```

while Im looking for

```
UPDATE /order/:id/items
```

(to update multiple items at once)

My current trick is:

```
resources :orders do
   resources :items, only:[] do
       collection do
           get 'edit'
           patch action:'update', :as => '' # gives us order_items_path()
        end
   end
end
```

Is there a better way to declare the routes?

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to use `resource` in place of `resources`:

```
resources :orders do
  resource :items
end
```